# Different results by using destructuring - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, destructuring

I understand that these two calls ****should** **return** the **same value****. I think the assignment I made is wrong but I don't see how to do it right.

**info2 ()** returns the correct value while **info ()** does not.

```
Client.prototype.info2 = function () {
    return (this.AccountType())
}
```

```
Client.prototype.info = function () {
    const {AccountType} = this
    return (AccountType())
}
```

------- All code -------

```
function Client(name, balance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
}

Client.prototype.AccountType = function () {
    const {balance} = this
    let type;

    if (balance >= 10000) {
        type = 'Platinum'
    } else if (balance >= 5000) {
        type = 'Gold'
    } else {
        type = 'Standard'
    }
    return type;
}

//Expected result: 'Gold'
// Result: 'Gold'

Client.prototype.info = function () {
    const {AccountType} = this
    return (AccountType())
}
//Expected result: 'Gold'
// Result: 'Standard'

Client.prototype.info2 = function () {
    return (this.AccountType())
}
//Expected result: 'Gold'
// Result: 'Gold'

//instances

const Pedro = new Client('Pedro', 8000)
```

Comment: No, they shouldn't. By separating the property access from the call, you've broken the link that sets `this` during the call to the expected value. See the linked questions' answers for details.

Comment: Side note: There's no need for `()` around the operand to `return` unless you want a line break just after the `return` (in which case you do need `()` -- with the first `(` on the same line as `return` -- because otherwise ASI will bite you).